# How is 節 being used here?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

In a visual novel I am currently I am playing, the MC says this while thinking to himself:

> ここは....嫌われたにしろ怒らせたにしろとにかくまずは謝るのが節のはずだ

The context is, that he is currently going out with his girlfriend, who he tried to kiss a day earlier which ended up in him getting slapped (they aren’t used to each other enough yet), and he is thinking of apologizing to her at this moment.

The two meanings that come to mind are:

> （１）ある事柄の行われるとき。時期。おり。ころ。「その―はお世話になりました」

> （２）自分の信念を守り続けること。みさお。節操。操守。「―を守る」

I could imagine it with the first meaning “occasion”, as “This should be the right occasion to apologize”, but I could also imagine the second meaning, “principal, integrity”, “Apologizing here would be the correct choice”. Tho, the first one seems more natural.

Which meaning is 節 representing here? Also, is it common to use 節 like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misreading [筋{すじ}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%AD%8B/#je-39048) for 節{ふし}.

> 3〔道理〕reason; logic
>
> 筋を通す
> stick to one's principles
>
> 筋が通った話なら聞きましょう
> I will listen to reason.／I will listen to what you have to say if it is reasonable.
>
> 君の言うことは筋が通らないよ
> What you say 「isn't logical [doesn't make sense/doesn't hold water].

So まずは謝るのが筋のはずだ means *What is reasonable to do should be to apologize first*.

Xするのが筋だ is almost a set phrase saying that doing X is the reasonable thing according to social norms and/or given the situation.

Comment: Ah.... I feel so stupid now. I am sorry for wasting everyone’s time with this, I will delete the post, thank you for clearing the misunderstanding for me.